# Pointer incrementing in C

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the following code:

```
unsigned short i;
unsigned short a;
unsigned char *pInput = (unsigned char *)&i;

pInput[0] = 0xDE;
pInput[1] = 0x01;

a = ((unsigned short)(*pInput++)) << 8 | ((unsigned short)(*pInput++));
```

Why the value of a is 0xDEDE, not 0xDE01?

Comment: In short (among other errors), there is no guarantee for the left `pInput++` to execute first and the right `pInput++` to execute second. In other words, you are modifying pInput twice in the same expression which is technically called _undefined behavior_ and even if demons fly out of your nose, you can't complain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code invokes **undefined behavior**. The reason is that `pInput` is modifying more than once between two [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). You may get anything, either expected or unexpected result. Nothing can be said.

C99 states that:

> **Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression**. Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored.

Read [c-faq 3.8](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html) for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There are no [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) between the two increments to `pInput`, which provokes undefined behaviour.

Cut it into **sequences** like so:

```
a = ((unsigned short)(*pInput++)) << 8;
a |= ((unsigned short)(*pInput++));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ((unsigned short)(*pInput++)) << 8 | ((unsigned short)(*pInput++));
```

You are using post increment, the ++ is applied after the execution of the line.

a will take the same value as if doing:

```
a = ((unsigned short)(*pInput)) << 8 | ((unsigned short)(*pInput));
```

If you want it to be 0xDE01 you have to do:

```
a = ((unsigned short)(*pInput)) << 8 | ((unsigned short)(*(pInput+1)));
```

Comment: I think you got it backwards: a = ((unsigned short)(*pInput)) << 8 | ((unsigned short)(*(pInput+1)));